# How to deal with dynamic parameter name in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

Login page is having dynamic password field name: every time user visits the login page field name looks like `PASSWORD_673834937`, and on next visit, it looks like `PASSWORD_673857943`.

I have created many scripts which were working as of today, but in latest build they bring in this change to the password field... before this it was always `PASSWORD` only. So all my scripts were failing. What is the workaround, so that all my scripts start working with dynamic field name?

[OLD JMETER SCRIPT using name as "PASSWORD"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLXBm.png)

[NEW changes to the password field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C58rN.png)

Comment: You are required to post a minimal example of your code that shows the problem [mcve]

Comment: Look at the response of your `register.asp` sampler. Most likely it contains the current name of the password field. You need to extract that name using RegEx extractor into a variable, and use a variable (rather than static name) in the parameter name for that field

Comment: yes you are right response of register.asp is having password field as PASSWORD_673986453, how to extract it and pass it as Parameter name to Login page

Comment: using RegEx extractor; post a response of that sampler if you want someone to look at it.

Comment: <input TYPE="password" NAME="PASSWORD_699464539" size="30" class="loginInput passWrd tal valm" maxlength="50" title="Password" autocomplete="off">

Comment: see the answer below

Answer (score 1):

1. Under `register.asp` sampler, add [RegEx Post-Processor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor)
2. Specify the following parameters:

   [image]

(i.e. the regular expression is `<input TYPE="password" NAME="([^"]+)"`)

3. In HTTP Request, in the row where password is provided, specify variable created by RegEx Post-Processor in Field name, instead of static name. For example, since the variable I created above is called `PasswordFieldName`, the HTTP Sampler should look like this (omitting irrelevant parameters):

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a matter of missing [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-load-testing-scenarios-jmeter-part-1-correlations), you would need this sooner or later given you continue playing with JMeter.

The idea of bypassing dynamic parameters is building your Test Plan as follows:

- Request 1 (open login page)

  - Extract dynamic parameters and store them into JMeter Variables
- Request 2 (perform login) providing credentials and all dynamic variables from the previous step

  1. Add [CSS/JQuery Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor) (be aware that [it is not recommended to use regular expressions to work with HTML data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2897748)) as a child of the `register.asp` page and configure it as follows:

     - Reference Name: anything meaningful, i.e. `name`
     - CSS/JQuery Expression: `input[title=Password]`
     - Attribute: `name`
  2. Replace `PASSWORD_673834937` with `${name}` in the new script.